# Testing that Rails verify_authenticity_token is being skipped

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, functional-testing

I have an action in a Rails 3.2 application which skips verification of the authenticity token, as follows:

```
skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token, only: [:my_action_name]
```

However, from time to time, this gets removed accidentally by developers, and the app fails silently, losing the user's session on that particular (AJAX) action.

From within my functional tests, what is the simplest way to test that this before filter is being skipped for that action? I.e. what is the simplest way to test that this line has not been removed?

Answer (score 0):

I would run:

```
before_filter :verify_authenticity_token, only: [:add, :your, :actions, :here]
```

and add only the actions you want to run verify_authenticity_token on

Comment: To put it another way then, how would you test that it won't later be set to run on `:my_action_name` by a developer who doesn't yet understand the implications of doing so?